# visual estudio vs code no muestra carpeta .git en el proyecto

Tags: visual-studio, vscode

estoy probando git y tengo un problema, creo una carpeta para un proyecto que se llama "calendario"
cuando inicio git me crea dentro una carpeta .git que es la que va a estar manejando todos los cambios que se hagan si? 
ahora bien, cuando abro esa carpeta con VS code no me muestra la carpeta .git para poder trabajar dentro :( 
espero puedan ayudarme con esto.

[image: visual estudio vs code no muestra carpeta .git en el proyecto]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es necesario tan siguiera ingresar a la carpeta `.git` ya que esta se gestiona con los comando `git` te recomiendo ver esta guía https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html

Comment: ¿Sí estás desplegando la carpeta? Veo que está colapsada, dale en la flecha que apunta hacia la derecha al lado del nombre de la carpeta.

Comment: Si si esta revisado el archivo y efectivamente no logro verlo desde vs code, pero me explican por aca que no es necesario manipular la carpeta ya que se puede hacer desde la consola con el comando .git,
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! ;)

Comment: @BiTMAU por que has revertido mi edicion? las dos fotos son exactamente la misma

Comment: perdón no fue mi intención

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code (y cualquier IDE) ignorará y ocultará esa carpeta porque no debes tocarla. Los datos guardados dentro son los que usará el cliente Git para gestionar tu proyecto, pero tu código (y todo lo demás) debe estar **fuera** de esa carpeta, algo como lo siguiente (variará según el lenguaje de programación):

```
.miProyecto/
  |- .git/      directorio gestionado por Git
  |- src/       directorio con tu código
  |- assets/    directorio con otros recursos de tu proyecto
  |- .gitignore fichero con ficheros a ignorar por Git
  |- ...        cualquier otro fichero o directorio que quieras incluir
```

Comment: Ahh comprendo! si me parecía raro que este como oculta! voy a revisarlo nuevamente, muchas gracias por tu respuesta!